# "flutter run -d windows --release" works but executable doesn't

Tags: windows, flutter, package, ffi

I do have a strange behavior with a flutter package I am building. It uses FFI to integrate a custom-made c++ library.
When I run `flutter run -d windows --release` the code starts and I do have the window with the code running.
However, when I go to the directory where the executable is stored and I run it, the program starts but the library is not loaded. I do see also that when I run `flutter test`, it complains that it cannot load the library. I have checked that the dll's needed are there using dependenciesGUI.exe and it seems that everything is fine, at least on my side. I do see however that within *kernel32.dll* I am missing *ext-ms-win-oobe-query-l1-1-0.dll*.
I am using Visual Studio 2022 with the x64 configuration.

Any idea on what could be the issue? For me it is VERY puzzling to be able to run the software through flutter but not with the executable directly.

Thanks!
Yours,

Pi-r

**EDIT:**

- I compared my package with a fresh package built with flutter. With a fresh package, the behavior is the one expected: I can have the program run normally or with flutter run.
- I compared the libraries of the clean package with the ones linked in my package. They are the same (with the same missing dlls which do not seem to pose an issue).
- I also checked that the exported functions I needed where present -> It is the case.
- The only difference I can see is that using flutter run adds a series of libraries to the path. Has I am a Linux person, I do not know of a tool that could be used to detect what is the missing library. I am open to write a separated c++ code that would load the library if it could help me identify what is the issue... ANY tips/tricks would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you get any error on `flutter doctor -v` and can you make sure you navigate to release directory

Comment: I checked that. I checked that I am in the release folder but not luck...

Comment: Use `dumpbin /dependents <dll or exe>` to find out the missing files and copy them to your folder.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue I had and it is related to a different behavior under Linux and under Windows (as you will guess, I am a Linux person).

When compiled under Linux, I can force the compiler to link multiple libraries relatively to my main library. I discovered that this is not the case under Windows. Either the dlls are in the executable folder or in the Path.

For the sake of code clarity, my package uses two different libraries. Library A, which is compiled from flutter with the ffi package, called library B. First the second library was in the asset folder and with the relative linking of Linux, it was working perfectly. But it did not work under Windows until I explicitly copied the two in the same directory of the executable.

The solution was then to ensure that both libraries are copied correctly ***in the directory of the flutter executable***. This can be done easily if you add the dependent libraries to the bundle variable in the CMakeLists.txt of the package.

However, this doesn't work when you do the testing (flutter test). As the bundle mechanism seems to be not propagated to the test function. Therefore here, the only solution is to copy the dependent libraries to the root directory of the source code :vomiting_face:

I must point out that this is only the case under Windows, for Linux, it works out of the box...